# d3/jQuery - On start select all, but when one is selected - deselect all except that one, but allow individual selection of each element again

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm struggling with my selector function. Namely, allowing users to move from everything selected with the .selected class applied to each arc - to decidedly clicking one and de-selecting all the other elements, whilst still allowing for users to select all the items again. Towards the end of my JS script, I have attempted to include some jQuery that would action that. But I am finding that it is not working, or for some reason d3 and jquery conflict and my code is not read.

Would you please be able to help me figure out this control flow? Thank you.

Steps:

1. All elements are selected.
2. Selected one.
3. Remove class of selected of all elements except the selected element in step 2
4. Allow for users to reselect the elements one at a time. So, from 3, to 1, to 2, to 3, and back to 2. Essentially a function that works solely on start-up only.

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 800;

const svg = d3.select('#radial-chart')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', w)
.attr('height', h);

    const arc = d3.arc()

var arcData = [
    {domain: '1', innerRadius: 0, outerRadius: (h/1.75), startAngle: Math.PI * -20/180, endAngle: Math.PI * 20/180},
    {domain: '2', innerRadius: 0, outerRadius: (h/1.25), startAngle: Math.PI * 20/180, endAngle: Math.PI * 60/180},
    {domain: '3', innerRadius: 0, outerRadius: (h/1.15), startAngle: Math.PI * 60/180, endAngle: Math.PI * 100/180},
];
// Order needs to be from JSON
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(["1", "2", "3",])
.range(["#E8A82B", "#000000", "#2B55E8"]);
const slices = arcData.map(d => arc(d));

const handleMouseOver = (d, i, n) => {
    svg.selectAll('path')
        .transition().duration(300)
        .style('opacity', 0.35);

    d3.select(n[i])
    .transition().duration(300)
        .style('opacity', 0.35)
}

const handleMouseOut = (d, i, n) => {
    svg.selectAll('path')
    .transition().duration(300)
        .style('opacity', 0.35)
        .style('stroke-width', 0)

}

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(slices)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(325,550)')
    .attr("d", d => d)
    .attr("id", (d, i) => "arc" + i)
    .style("fill", (d,i) => colorScale(i))
    .style("z-index", 100)
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr('class', 'selected')
    .on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
    .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut)
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).classed("selected", d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? false : true)
        d3.select('image#arc' + i).classed("selected", d3.select(this).classed("selected") ? true: false)

})




$('path').on('click', function(){
    if($(('arc0')&&('arc1')&&('arc2')).hasClass('selected')){
      $('path').removeClass('selected')
    }})
```

```css
.selected {
    transition: opacity 0.0s linear;
    -webkit-transition:  opacity 0.0s linear;
    -moz-transition:  opacity 0.0s linear;
    opacity: 1!important
}

image#arc0, image#arc1, image#arc2{
    transition: opacity 0s linear;
    -webkit-transition:  opacity 0s linear;
    -moz-transition:  opacity 0s linear;
    opacity: 0.35
}

image#arc0:hover, image#arc1:hover, image#arc2:hover {
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition:  opacity 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition:  opacity 0.3s linear;
    opacity: 1
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="radial-chart.js"></script>
        <div id="radial-chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to select and deselect slices, but if nothing is selected, then you want to select all slices. Don't use classes to store that kind of information, just store them in an array instead. I used a [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) because it's even easier to remove items from.

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 800;
var selected = new Set();

const svg = d3.select('#radial-chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

const arc = d3.arc()

var arcData = [{
    domain: '1',
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: (h / 1.75),
    startAngle: Math.PI * -20 / 180,
    endAngle: Math.PI * 20 / 180
  },
  {
    domain: '2',
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: (h / 1.25),
    startAngle: Math.PI * 20 / 180,
    endAngle: Math.PI * 60 / 180
  },
  {
    domain: '3',
    innerRadius: 0,
    outerRadius: (h / 1.15),
    startAngle: Math.PI * 60 / 180,
    endAngle: Math.PI * 100 / 180
  },
];
// Order needs to be from JSON
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["1", "2", "3", ])
  .range(["#E8A82B", "#000000", "#2B55E8"]);
const slices = arcData.map(d => arc(d));

const handleMouseOver = (d, i, n) => {
  svg.selectAll('path')
    .transition().duration(300)
    .style('opacity', 0.35);

  d3.select(n[i])
    .transition().duration(300)
    .style('opacity', 0.35)
}

const handleMouseOut = (d, i, n) => {
  svg.selectAll('path')
    .transition().duration(300)
    .style('opacity', 0.35)
    .style('stroke-width', 0)

}

svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(slices)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(325,550)')
  .attr("d", d => d)
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "arc" + i)
  .style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i))
  .style("z-index", 100)
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr('class', 'selected')
  .on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
  .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut)
  .on('click', function(_, i) {
    if (selected.has(i)) {
      selected.delete(i);
    } else {
      selected.add(i);
    }

    d3.selectAll("path")
      .classed("selected", function(_, j) {
        return selected.size === 0 || selected.has(j);
      });
  });
```

```css
.selected {
  transition: opacity 0.0s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.0s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.0s linear;
  opacity: 1!important
}

#arc0,
#arc1,
#arc2 {
  transition: opacity 0s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0s linear;
  opacity: 0.35
}

#arc0:hover,
#arc1:hover,
#arc2:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="radial-chart.js"></script>
<div id="radial-chart"></div>
```